# useEffect empty array callback does not work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, react-hooks

My useEffect runs forever even though it grabs the details but when I add the empty array callback since I only want it to run once, it does not run.

Front End Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function AdminPage(props) {

    const [ userId, setUserId ] = useState('');
    const [ products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const getProducts = (id) => {
        Axios.post('/api/product/adminProducts', id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.products)
            setProducts(res.data.products)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.user.userData) {
            console.log(props.user.userData._id)
            setUserId(props.user.userData._id)
        }    
        const userid = {
            id: userId
        }
        getProducts(userid)
    })

    return (
        <div style={{paddingTop: '50px'}}>
            {userId}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If i make my use effect like the below, I get unhandled reject status 400 error and not even the userData value from my redux.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(props.user.userData) {
            console.log(props.user.userData._id)
            setUserId(props.user.userData._id)
        }    
        const userid = {
            id: userId
        }
        getProducts(userid)
    }, [])
```

Backend code

````
router.post('/adminProducts', (req, res) => {
    Product.find({ writer: req.body.id}, (err, products) => {
        if(!products) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
        }
        console.log(products)
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, products })
    })
})```
````

Comment: check your `axios.post` 2nd argument

Answer (score 0):

That's because `props.user.userData` is undefined or otherwise missing on the first render so the effect is run only once with that value. You need to list that as dependency in `useEffect` so it's triggered properly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.user.userData) {
    console.log(props.user.userData._id)
    setUserId(props.user.userData._id)
    const userid = {
      id: props.user.userData._id
    }
    getProducts(userid)
  }

}, [props.user.userData])
```

Comment: Hey I tried this, but it did not work. There was another answer where that person told me to add [props.user.userData, userId] as the callback and that  worked. I dont know why that person removed his/her answer but still thank you @Clarity